# Normalize an array of objects in the flattest way for the Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, normalize

But I believe I’m doing it wrong because it doesn’t help much. The store is still too complex and therefore I need to use some recursive stuff in reducer to update the state.

Moreover, a deeply nested state makes working with react-redux connect() very hard too, because it does only a shallow comparison.

The shape of a reponse be like:

```
const questionData = {questions:[
{
    id: '1312fsadf123',
    state: QUESTION.state[0].value,
    chapter_id: '',
    content_type: '',
    question_type: '',
    difficult_degree: '',
    question: {
        content: [],
        answers: [
            {
                id: '324',
                text: [],
                answer_key: 'a',
                correct: true,
            },
            {
                id: '323',
                text: [],
                answer_key: 'b',
                correct: true,
            },
            {
                id: '322',
                text: [],
                answer_key: 'c',
                correct: true,
            },
            {
                id: '321',
                text: [],
                answer_key: 'd',
                correct: true,
            },
        ],
    },
    solution_suggesstion: [],
    solution_detail: [],
    note: [],
    attachment: { questionFile: '', solutionDetailFile: '' },
    question_child: ['1213'],
},
{
    id: '1213',
    state: QUESTION.state[0].value,
    chapter_id: '',
    content_type: '',
    question_type: '',
    difficult_degree: '',
    question: {
        content: [],
        answers: [
            {
                id: '324',
                text: [],
                answer_key: 'a',
                correct: true,
            },
            {
                id: '323',
                text: [],
                answer_key: 'b',
                correct: true,
            },
            {
                id: '322',
                text: [],
                answer_key: 'c',
                correct: true,
            },
            {
                id: '321',
                text: [],
                answer_key: 'd',
                correct: true,
            },
        ],
    },
    solution_suggesstion: [],
    solution_detail: [],
    note: [],
    attachment: { questionFile: '', solutionDetailFile: '' },
},
```

] };

I’ve tried to use a normalizr tool like this:

```
const answer = new schema.Entity('answers');
const question = new schema.Entity('questions');
const mySchema = { questions: [question] };
export const normalizedData = normalize(questionData, mySchema);
console.log('normalizedData', normalizedData);
```

[myConsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Rph.png)
I want it to be

```
{
entities: {
    questions: {1213: {…,question.answers:[324,323,322,321]}, 1312fsadf123: {…}},
    answer: [{...},{...},{...}]
},
result:{question:[1213,1312fsadf123]}}
```

Please help me !

Comment: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape. Please go through and then restructued it.You dont need tool for this

Comment: You can use this to get all question id `questionData.questions.map(({id}) => id)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const questionData = {
  questions: [{
      id: '1312fsadf123',
      state: 'QUESTION.state[0].value',
      chapter_id: '',
      content_type: '',
      question_type: '',
      difficult_degree: '',
      question: {
        content: [],
        answers: [{
            id: '324',
            text: [],
            answer_key: 'a',
            correct: true,
          },
          {
            id: '323',
            text: [],
            answer_key: 'b',
            correct: true,
          },
          {
            id: '322',
            text: [],
            answer_key: 'c',
            correct: true,
          },
          {
            id: '321',
            text: [],
            answer_key: 'd',
            correct: true,
          },
        ],
      },
      solution_suggesstion: [],
      solution_detail: [],
      note: [],
      attachment: {
        questionFile: '',
        solutionDetailFile: ''
      },
      question_child: ['1213'],
    },
    {
      id: '1213',
      state: 'QUESTION.state[0].value',
      chapter_id: '',
      content_type: '',
      question_type: '',
      difficult_degree: '',
      question: {
        content: [],
        answers: [{
            id: '324',
            text: [],
            answer_key: 'a',
            correct: true,
          },
          {
            id: '323',
            text: [],
            answer_key: 'b',
            correct: true,
          },
          {
            id: '322',
            text: [],
            answer_key: 'c',
            correct: true,
          },
          {
            id: '321',
            text: [],
            answer_key: 'd',
            correct: true,
          },
        ],
      },
      solution_suggesstion: [],
      solution_detail: [],
      note: [],
      attachment: {
        questionFile: '',
        solutionDetailFile: ''
      },
    }
  ]
};

const baseQuestions = questionData.questions;
const { questions, answers } = baseQuestions.reduce(({ questions = {}, answers = [] } = {}, baseQuestion) => {
  const { id: questionID, question: { answers: baseAnswers } } = baseQuestion;
  const answersInQuestionProperty = baseAnswers.map(({ id }) => Number(id));
  const newQuestionObj = Object.assign({ answers: answersInQuestionProperty }, baseQuestion);
  questions[questionID] = newQuestionObj;
  answers.push(baseAnswers);
  return { questions, answers };
}, {});

const finalObj = { entities: { questions, answers }};
finalObj.result = { question: Object.keys(questions) };
console.log(finalObj);
```

That's the general idea - just use `.reduce` and keep extracting and destructuring until the data is structured the way you want.